# Apache Cassandra DefaultRetryPolicy not supporting network disconnections?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm using datastax cassandra driver core 3.1.0, and to start learning cassandra I have setup a 3 node cluster (3 VM running in my laptop).

The cluster connection is done this way (passing a list of contact points):

```
public static Cluster createCassandraRockSolidCluster(String... contactPoints) {

    // Connect to the cluster
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(contactPoints).withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().build())).build();
    return cluster;
}
```

I have created a test which periodically do the same query to the cluster, having set the ConsistencyLevel.ONE.

My expectation was that if one or even two of the nodes fail, the query still would be able to get results (due to ConsistencyLevel.ONE and DefaultRetryPolicy).

What is happening is that:

1. If I shut down a node or even two of them, by stopping cassandra service, the client's query works as I was expecting: it retrieves the result without any issue.
2. But, if I virtually "disconnect the cable" from the network adapter of one server to make it unaccesible, then a Time-Out exception is raised, and one query is lost (the next query is able to retrieve the data).

This is not what I was expecting, and I wonder if it is my mistake or it is a bug in the java client library.

On the other hand, if I catch the Exception, and "re-execute" the timed-out query, it works, but I expected that this retry would be managed by the DefaultRetryPolicy.

So, to provide additional robustness to my client, I have created this method:

```
    protected static ResultSet executeRockSolid(Session session, BoundStatement boundStatement) {
    ResultSet results = null;
    try {
        results = session.execute(boundStatement);
    } catch (OperationTimedOutException e) {
        System.err.format("Retrying. Caused by: %s", e.toString());
        results = session.execute(boundStatement);
    } catch (TransportException e) {
        System.err.format("Retrying. Caused by: %s", e.toString());
        results = session.execute(boundStatement);
    } catch (ReadTimeoutException e) {
        System.err.format("Retrying. Caused by: %s", e.toString());
        results = session.execute(boundStatement);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    return results;
}
```

But, I really don't like to use my own code for something that I think it should be provided by the client.

So, the question is:

Is the behaviour I observe the normal one or is it a bug?

If it is the normal one, what would be the best option to make the client support "server disconnection from the network" transparently?

If the best option is create a custom retry policy, what would be the parameters / implementation?

Comment: are you marking statements idempotent?

Comment: No, I wasn't making them idempotent, and you're right, after I set the statement idempotent, the queries executions are not throwing time-out exceptions, but now, the "issue" has moved to the session.prepareStatement method, which, sometimes, throws a TransportException as in the following example got from the log of the test application: Preparing statement --------------------------------------------
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/10.0.2.15:9042] Connection has been closed. Next iteration, it run without any Exception.

Comment: you should only prepare once at start up of application, if your doing it dynamically your better off not using prepared statements.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I can't set the consitency level or idempotent a simple query, it has to be a prepared statement. Anyway, it might fail the first time I create the prepared statement, right?

Comment: create a SimpleStatement and you can set consistency level and idempotent without prepared. Worth noting that you can ignore the prepared statement logging. If it tries to send a statement to an instance that doesn't have it prepared it will just re-prepare under covers